# how to properly debug webpack application?

Tags: webpack

webpack is building a unique bundle so when I try debug my application I can't see from which file the is from.

With library it's easy to have a 100k lines application, what's your solution to address this issue ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have enabled source maps you can use one of the easiest to config (this is the most popular solution) `cheap-module-eval-source-map`.
In `webpack.config.js` add this:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    // ...
};
```